# Delete Lines in a textfile

Tags: c#

Hi I have a text file with table schema and data when user checks not schema required then i need to delete  schema and leave the data . I am using StreamReader to read the file and checking one condition and it should delete all the lines in the file till it satisfies my condition . 
Let say if i am checking

```
  using (StreamReader tsr = new StreamReader(targetFilePath))
        {
            do
            {
                string textLine = tsr.ReadLine() + "\r\n";

                {
                    if (textLine.StartsWith("INSERT INTO"))
                    {

                         // It should leave these lines 
                        // and no need to delete lines 
                    }

                    else
                    {
                      // it should delete the lines 
                    }

                }
            }
            while (tsr.Peek() != -1);
            tsr.Close();
```

Please suggest me how to delete lines and note if textline finds "InsertInto" it should not delete any content from there .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read in the file just the same way you were doing. However, if the line doesn't contain what you are looking for, you simply skip it. In the end, whatever data you are left over with you then write to a new text file.

```
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader tsr = new StreamReader(targetFilePath))
        {
            do
            {
                string textLine = tsr.ReadLine() + "\r\n";

                {
                    if (textLine.StartsWith("INSERT INTO"))
                    {

                        newText.Append(textLine + Environment.NewLine);
                    }

                }
            }
            while (tsr.Peek() != -1);
            tsr.Close();
        }

        System.IO.TextWriter w = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\newFile.txt");
        w.Write(newText.ToString());
        w.Flush();
        w.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You should use StringBuilder instead of concatenate strings.... depending on the number of lines, it can be much more efficient

Comment: @Evan : Thanks Evan for the answer

Answer (score 6):

Use a second file where to put only required lines, and, at the end of the process, remove original file and rename new one to target file.

```
using (StreamReader tsr = new StreamReader(targetFilePath))
{
    using (StreamWriter tsw = File.CreateText(targetFilePath+"_temp"))
    {
         string currentLine;
         while((currentLine = tsr.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
             if(currentLine.StartsWith("A long time ago, in a far far away galaxy ..."))
             {
                    tsw.WriteLine(currentLine);
             }
         }
    }
}
File.Delete(targetFilePath);
File.Move(targetFilePath+"_temp",targetFilePath);
```

Comment: this code can be improved by renaming the original file instead of deleting it, just in case of an exception.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Linq:

```
File.WriteAllLines(targetFilePath, File.ReadAllLines(targetFilePath).Where(x => x.StartsWith("INSERT INTO")));
```

Comment: Your approach is nice, but in extreme case, the memory footprint of this single line of code will be at least as high as the whole file size (charset can raise this value). Fortunately, having a 100GB text file is not common ;)

Comment: @SteveB: That's correct - that's the price you pay for not using a temporary file in this case, everything must be loaded into memory. Alternatively could use `FileReadLines()` and write to a temporary file and then copy it over.

Comment: even a 5MB document is not common... with today's computers. This won't be a big issue. It can even qualified as premature optimization to work line by line ;)